# how does ADO.NET know that a SQL Server concurrency violation has occurred?

Tags: ado.net, concurrency, sqldataadapter

I don't understand how ADO.NET recognizes a concurrency violation unless it's doing something beyond what I'm telling it to do, inside its "black box".

My update query in SQL Server 2000 does something like the following example, which is simplified; if the rowversion passed to the stored proc by the client doesn't match the rowversion in the database, the where-clause will fail, and no rows will be updated:

```
      create proc UpdateFoo
      @rowversion timestamp OUTPUT,
      @id int,
      @foodescription varchar(255)

      as UPDATE FOO set description = @foodescription
      where id = @id and rowversion = @rowversion;

      if @@ROWCOUNT = 1
           select @rowversion from foo where id = @id;
```

I create a SqlCommand object and populate the parameters and assign the command object to the SqlDataAdapter's UpdateCommand property.   Then I invoke the data adapter's Update method.

There should indeed be a concurrency error because I deliberately change the database row in order to force a new rowversion. But how does ADO.NET know this? Is it doing something more than executing the command?

In the RowUpdated event of the SqlDataAdapter there will be a Concurrency error:

```
   MySqlDataAdapter += (sender, evt) =>
     {
       if ((evt.Status == UpdateStatus.Continue) && (evt.StatementType == StatementType.Update))
           {
                  // update succeeded
           }
           else
           { 

            // update failed, check evt.Errors
            }
      }
```

Is ADO.NET comparing the rowversions? Is it looking at @@rowcount?

Comment: I suspect that ADO.Net gets the number of rows affected for the last statement in a stored procedure. If it happens to be zero, ADO assumes a concurrency violation has occurred. I'm trying to figure out how to turn this off or work around it.

Comment: @Keith Walton: indeed, the ADO.NET library is looking only at the number of rows affected. A while ago I found the Microsoft source code and looked.